# app crash after DateTime.parse (DateTime.java) => Invalid date format . Error thrown null

Tags: flutter

I have an user who have this error :

```
Fatal Exception: io.flutter.plugins.firebase.crashlytics.FlutterError: FormatException: Invalid date format
. Error thrown null.
       at DateTime.parse(DateTime.java)
```

The error come from this part of my code

```
String myString ="";

  void myfunction() async{
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    String myString = prefs.getString("key")??"";

    _variable = myString!=null||myString!="" ? DateTime.parse("$myString") : DateTime.now();
  }
```

firebase crash point here

```
_variable = myString!=null||myString!="" ? DateTime.parse("$myString") : DateTime.now();
```

I don't understand because the error seems to found a null but my cause prevent null by forcing null to be DateTime.now();

I'm wrong ?

Comment: can you share what `data!` is?

Comment: what is `runtimeType` of  the `data` ?

Comment: It's a string with date format like that 2022-08-10 15:45:00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This exception occurs when the string you're passing to `DateTime.parse` is not a valid one.
You can consider using [`DateTime.tryParse`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.6/dart-core/DateTime/tryParse.html) which will return `null` instead of throwing a `FormatException` when the string is not valid.

```dart
final String myString = prefs.getString("key") ?? "";

final DateTime _variable = DateTime.tryParse(myString) ?? DateTime.now();
```

Comment: Bad news, after few days of testing, I have a crash report with the same error. I have well use tryParse like mentioned :'(

Comment: @Nitneuq the error (Null check operator used on a null value.) you have now is unrelated to the parsing of your DateTime, it is probably induced because of a bad usage of the `!` operator to force cast a nullable variable as non nullable.

Answer (score 2):

In this case Null condition comes TRUE so that result converting date formate is Empty. so please check this once

```
// here always empty data will assign. 
String myString = prefs.getString("key")??"";

DateTime _variable =  myString != "" ? DateTime.parse(myString) : DateTime.now();

print(_variable);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's very likely that your string in this code has invalid/empty string. And you are using wrong operation "||" as well.

```
_variable = myString!=null||myString!="" ? DateTime.parse("$myString") : DateTime.now();
```

But for a better approach, if your intention is simply replacing the date into **current date** in spite of parse exceptions, I suggest you do **DateTime.tryParse**

```
 _variable = DateTime.tryParse(myString) ?? DateTime.now();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime parse(String formattedString)
```

Constructs a new DateTime instance based on formattedString.
Throws a FormatException if the input string cannot be parsed.
To detect and reject invalid component values, use [DateFormat.parseStrict](https://pub.dev/documentation/intl/latest/intl/DateFormat/parseStrict.html) from the intl package.

more details on [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/DateTime/parse.html)

maybe you can try like below:

```
// convert data to string
_variable = data!=null ? DateTime.parse('$data') : DateTime.now();
```

Comment: data is well a String declared. I need to add ('$data') even if data is a String ?

Answer (score 0):

**[DateTime.parse](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.6/dart-core/DateTime/parse.html) method accepts a string as an input but the input which is passed to the method must be a valid one. If the input is invalid it throws FormatException**.

From the docs:

> The accepted inputs are currently:
>
> - A date: A signed four-to-six digit year, two digit month and two digit
>   day, optionally separated by - characters. Examples: "19700101",
>   "-0004-12-24", "81030-04-01".
> - An optional time part, separated from the date by either T or a space.
>   The time part is a two digit hour, then optionally a two digit minutes
>   value, then optionally a two digit seconds value, and then optionally
>   a '.' or ',' followed by at least a one digit second fraction. The
>   minutes and seconds may be separated from the previous parts by a ':'.
>   Examples: "12", "12:30:24.124", "12:30:24,124", "123010.50".
> - An optional time-zone offset part, possibly separated from the
>   previous by a space. The time zone is either 'z' or 'Z', or it is a
>   signed two digit hour part and an optional two digit minute part. The
>   sign must be either "+" or "-", and cannot be omitted. The minutes may
>   be separated from the hours by a ':'. Examples: "Z", "-10", "+01:30",
>   "+1130".
>
> This includes the output of both toString and toIso8601String, which
> will be parsed back into a DateTime object with the same time as the
> original.
>
> The result is always in either local time or UTC. If a time zone
> offset other than UTC is specified, the time is converted to the
> equivalent UTC time.
>
> Examples of accepted strings:
>
> "2012-02-27" "2012-02-27 13:27:00" "2012-02-27 13:27:00.123456789z"
> "2012-02-27 13:27:00,123456789z" "20120227 13:27:00" "20120227T132700"
> "20120227" "+20120227" "2012-02-27T14Z" "2012-02-27T14+00:00"
> "-123450101 00:00:00 Z": in the year -12345.
> "2002-02-27T14:00:00-0500": Same as "2002-02-27T19:00:00Z"

Check the format of the String coming from your api and see if it matches the given format above.
**Can you post an example string which you get from firebase, so as to further check?**

Answer (score 0):

For example the value is empty but not null the condition

```
myString!=null||myString!=""
```

Is true since it satisfies the condition that its not null. You have to check if not null AND not empty so using && should solve the issue

```dart
_variable = myString!=null && myString!="" ? DateTime.parse("$myString") : DateTime.now();
```

Also it's better to write

```dart
_variable = DateTime.tryParse('$myString') ?? DateTime.now();
```

This will try to parse the string and if it returns null then it will assign datetime. Now

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from a wrong handling of the possible NULL value.

In this part of the code you are reading a value from `SharedPreferences` and you implemented a check wether the value is null or not.
In case the value is null, `myString` is equal to empty string.
That means that whatever happens, myString cannot be null.

```
  String myString = prefs.getString("key")??"";
```

Then you want to load `_variable` with the date value.

- If `myString` has the date value, then `_variable` should contain that value parsed
- If `myString` is null or contains an empty string value `""` then `_variable` should contain `DateTime.now()`.

```
    _variable = myString!=null||myString!="" ? DateTime.parse("$myString") : DateTime.now();
```

The error is in the ternary operator condition:

```
    myString!=null||myString!=""
```

As I wrote in before:
*`myString` cannot be null*.

That means that the first check inside the condition `myString!=null` will always be `True`, and since the checks are in `OR` relation, the whole condition is gonna be `True`.
It doesn't matter if `myString!=""`.

This resolves in the exectution of the positive branch of the ternary operator: `DateTime.parse("$myString")`.

So, if `myString` is equal to `""`, then this gets executed `DateTime.parse("")` and the error is thrown.

Here's a possible solution:

```
    String myString = prefs.getString("key")??"";
    _variable = myString!="" ? DateTime.parse("$myString") : DateTime.now();
```